# Get currently created model id in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.2

I have some problem with getting model id:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'   => 'required|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
    ]);

    $data = $request->all();

    $page = new Page;

    $page->create($data);

    dd($page->id);

    return redirect()->route('admin.pages.index');
}
```

**$page->id return null...**

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is o/p of dd($page->toArray()) ? Also please post your  Page model.

Comment: have you set the "fillable" property on your model Page.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use Mass Assign of laravel you should do like this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request, [
        'title'   => 'required|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
    ]);

    $data = $request->all();

    $page = Page::create($data);

    dd($page->id);

    return redirect()->route('admin.pages.index');
}
```

then you can get id of page like this :

```
$page_id = $page->id
```

for more information :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#mass-assignment

and your model class should be like this (Fillable):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Page extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['title','content'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Mass Assign in model,

ex:   protected $fillable = ['id'];

Still no luck? Use this,

$page = Page::create($data);

dd($page->id;)